Create / update a new list based on comparing expected list vs actual list of unequal lengths
I'm working on a project where I've to compare a list (Actual) against another list (Expected). The Expected list is fixed but the Actual list can sometime have "additional element" or "spelling mistakes" or both. The example below has both.
Expected List: (length = 14)
exp = ['change of form','death certificate','authority form',
'payment form','lodgement form','supporting documentation',
'proof of authority','proof of executor','proof of identity',
'reverse form','statutory declaration','agreements',
'transfers','mediators'] 

                 

Actual List: (length = 15)
act = ['change of form','death certificatey',
'authority form','payment form','lodgement form','supporting documentation',
'proof of authority','proof of executor','proof of identity',**'proof of ownership'**,
'reverse form','statutory declaration','agreements','transfers','mediators']   # length = 15

Now my logic below,
import itertools
temp_new = []

if len(exp) < len(act):

  # extend the expected list 
  exp = exp[:len(act)] + ['']*(len(act) - len(exp)) 

# creating new list
for e,a in itertools.zip_longest(range(len(exp)),range(len(act))):
  temp_new += ['missing']
  if (act[a] in exp) or ( set(act[a].split()) & set(exp[e].split()) ):
    temp_new[a] = act[a]


Gives me the following output:
temp_new = ['change of form','death certificatey',
'authority form','payment form','lodgement form','supporting documentation',
'proof of authority','proof of executor','proof of identity',**'missing'**,
'reverse form','statutory declaration','agreements','transfers','mediators']

What I'm actually looking for is the following list:
expected_output = ['change of form','death certificate',
'authority form','payment form','lodgement form','supporting documentation',
'proof of authority','proof of executor','proof of identity',**'missing'**,
'reverse form','statutory declaration','agreements','transfers','mediators']'

Can someone please help me rectify my current logic OR provide me with a new one?

How many characters different would a word need to be to be classified as a "spelling mistake" compared to being classified as an "additional element" ?

I am not sure why this question got a downvote, it looks quite interesting. With a bit of clarification it is a great question.

This could be as simple as appending exp[a] rather than act[e]. That will add "certificate" rather than "certificatey".
By using the in keyword, each pass through actual is also a pass through expected. You may as well explicitly use a nested loop.
def compare_lists(exp, act):
    temp_new = []

    range_start = 0  # ensure that elements in lists are in order
    for a in act:
        append_val = 'missing'
        for exp_idx in range(range_start, len(exp)):
            e = exp[exp_idx]
            if (e == a) or _string_partial_match(e, a):
                append_val = e
                range_start = range_start + 1
                break

        temp_new.append(append_val)

    return temp_new

def _string_partial_match(e:str, a:str):
    # return set(a.split()) & set(e.split())
    return any([(ew == aw) for ew, aw in zip(e.split(), a.split())])


This function returns:
['change of form', 'death certificate', 'authority form', 'payment form', 'lodgement form', 'supporting documentation', 'proof of authority', 'proof of executor', 'proof of identity', 'missing', 'reverse form', 'statutory declaration', 'agreements', 'transfers', 'mediators']
If it's OK for a value in the actual list to match an earlier value in the expected list, then you can do away with the range_start variable and just write for e in exp:.

Thank you for the logic , it does help me get the expected list output.

I'd be tempted to approach this using sets.
To find all the items in one set that also exist in the other, it's a one-liner, then you can finesse how you deal with those edge-cases that you might classify as being spelling vs additional values.
So, broadly:
exp = ['change of form','death certificate','authority form', 'payment form','lodgement form','supporting documentation', 'proof of authority','proof of executor','proof of identity', 'reverse form','statutory declaration','agreements', 'transfers','mediators']

act = ['change of form','death certificatey', 'authority form','payment form','lodgement form','supporting documentation', 'proof of authority','proof of executor','proof of identity','proof of ownership', 'reverse form','statutory declaration','agreements','transfers','mediators']

exp_s = set(exp)
act_s = set(act)

exp_s.intersection(act_s)

>>  {'agreements',
    'authority form',
    'change of form',
    'lodgement form',
    'mediators',
    'payment form',
    'proof of authority',
    'proof of executor',
    'proof of identity',
    'reverse form',
    'statutory declaration',
    'supporting documentation',
    'transfers'}

Leaving you to classify the ones that don't match.
I like to use the following function to express the content of two sets I'm matching as a kind of Venn diagram:

def diffset(S1, S2):
    L = S1.difference(S2)
    I = S1.intersection(S2)
    R = S2.difference(S1)
    return L, I, R

L,I,R = diffset(exp_s, act_s)

Which gives me 3 new sets, L is the items in exp_s that don't have a match in act_s, I contains all the "good" items that are in both sets, and R contains all those items in act_s that didn't have a match in exp_s.
In the data provided, this gives:
L = {'death certificate'}

I = {'agreements',
    'authority form',
    'change of form',
    'lodgement form',
    'mediators',
    'payment form',
    'proof of authority',
    'proof of executor',
    'proof of identity',
    'reverse form',
    'statutory declaration',
    'supporting documentation',
    'transfers'}

R = {'death certificatey', 'proof of ownership'}

So we've got I, now we just need to classify the contents in R as being either spelling mistakes, or "new" items, with L containing the reference set of so-far unmatched items.
There's options here, like calculating the Levenshtein distance, but difflib has a neat and easy function for this kind of thing, so:
spellings_s = set()
new_items_s = set()
import difflib
for r in R:
    spelling_candidates = difflib.get_close_matches(r, L)
    if len(spelling_candidates)>0:
        spellings_s.add(r)
    else:
        new_items_s.add(r)

Which should categorise the contents of R into either spelling diffs, or new items.
So:
spellings_s

>> {'death certificatey'}

and
new_items_s

>> {'proof of ownership'}

There's lots of nuance you could add here, and in the above routine, I'm not removing possible matches from the option set once spelling-matches have been found, but hopefully that gives a broad outline of a possible approach.
